# AbstractUser is not working Django ! (Substituting a custom User model)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

App name is **"backend"**

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    fb_userid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

**Settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'backend.apps.BackendConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'bffcode',
]
```

**Error:**

[image]

```
ERRORS:
backend.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustomUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
backend.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
bffcode.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'CustomUser.groups'.
bffcode.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'CustomUser.user_permissions'.
```

I'm trying to Substitute User model in my project but i'm not able to create migrations

Comment: Don't import User, you're not using it.

Comment: Please do NOT post images of the error - copy-paste the text version.

Comment: The traceback complains about `CustomUser` while your model doesn't seem to have it. What is this class about ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel not importing User, still if you are Changing to a custom user model mid-project, there are consequence due to  limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models,

the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL must be created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you’ll have dependency issues.

[django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/)